# Interpreting this piece of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
 var f = function () {
     var x = 1;
     g = function () {
         x = 2;
     };
     g();
     return x;
 };
```

When running it like this:

```
> f();
> 2
> g();
> undefined
> x;
> undefined
```

Actually I knew why `f()` return 1, but now I have a new question: why `x` return `undefined` after invoked `g()`?

I declared function `g()` without using the `var` keyword so function `g` is now in global object. Then I invoke `g` and I think function `g` should create a new global variable `x` in global object with value `2` cause I didn't using `var` keyword. But actually `x` is just return `undefined` and why?

Anyway, thx all you guys for help me!

PS: All those code run in Node.JS REPL.

Comment: `g` doesn’t return anything, because there’s no `return` statement in `g`. `x` is scoped to `f`; it should actually throw a ReferenceError.

Comment: "g" and "x" is inside "f", "g" and "x" are private to f's outside

Comment: Sorry about mistyping `f()` as `g()` and I corrected it now.

Comment: Okay, why did you expect `f` to return `1`? Try to go through the code line-by-line and explain it to us.

Answer (score 4):

Well to answer your questions and clarify things here:

> I thought `g()` should return `1` but it was `2`.

No `g()` doesn't return anything, it don't have a `return` statement, so it won't return `1` nor `2`.

> And why `x` return `undefined` after I invoked `g()`?

And `x` is local to `f` function, so it will throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`, if you call it from outside `f` function.

**EDIT:**

After your Edit you asked:

> I thought `f()` should return `1` but it was `2`.

Well in that case I would say that this is the right behaviour and the expected result from calling `f()`, it should return `2` because `x` is local to `f()` function and `g()` can access this local variable as it's local to `f()` too, so when you intialize `x` to `1` in `f` and then call `g()` before returning `x`, it will set `x` to `2` that's why you get `2`.

Comment: Yeap, nothing to add here.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes indeed, as simple as that.

Comment: Sorry about mistyping `f()` as `g()` and I corrected it now.

Answer (score -2):

As you can see :

```
g = function () {
         x = 2;
};
```

Doesn't have a return statement <del>AND is declared within `f`'s scope (therefore not accessible through the global scope)</del> ; therefore it'll not return any value (hints the undefined).

For `f` :

```
 var f = function () {
     var x = 1;
     g = function () {
         x = 2;
     };
     g();
     return x;
 };
```

When you call `f` it declares a variable `x` and initializes it to 1.
Then you declare an "inner function" that modifies `x` (since `x` has been declared prior to `g` it can be accessed through `g`'s scope. After `g`'s declaration you call it, therefore x becomes 2. Therefore `f`'s return value is 2.

Comment: `g` returning `undefined` has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can call a function in the global scope if it has been defined in the scope of another function.

Comment: Vivick, what environment did you run that code in? I can call `g` just fine in any browser I have here, as long as `f` is called first.

Comment: Didn't see Manu didn't use `var` to declare `g`. Therefore it's only because it doesn't have a return statement (therefore returns undefined).